# Forbid bulk export in eslint (export * from)

Tags: javascript, eslint, eslintrc

Is there any way to forbid bulk exports in eslint? I want to forbid these exports:

```js
export * from './module-name';
```

Can't find appropriate eslint rule.

Answer (score 3):

Solution has been found! We need to use the following eslint rule:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "no-restricted-syntax": ["error", "ExportAllDeclaration"]
  }
}
```

More details you can find at [eslint docs](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-syntax). All available values for the `no-restricted-syntax` rule can be found [here](https://github.com/eslint/espree/blob/master/lib/ast-node-types.js).